# How to query in Follow/Unfollow Data Model

Tags: parse-platform

I saw [Anypic](https://parse.com/tutorials/anypic#follow) data model, I didn't understand how to query to find only the followers using that model.

For e.g.

- Day1 - A **follows** B
- Day2 - A **unfollows** B
- Day3 - A **follows** B

Now how will you frame a query to find the followers of B?

The solutions I could think of is

1. Gather the results of all 'Anyone who follows/unfollows B' in desc order of created date, then run a 'for loop' on the results and select only the most recent activity to determine if A does follow B at present. This solution makes it slow. I wish I could do it within the query.
2. Store this relationship in a separate relation called "follows" and then additionally store this relationship in a join table like Anypic model to preserve metadata. This requires 2 api requests & it adds redundancy,  plus it makes db inconsistent over a period of time, for e.g. after success of "follows" relation.save(), we try to store this in join table(2nd api request), now if the join table save fails due to some reason, we'll have the relation in "follows" but we won't have its metadata.

FYI, I'm doing this in cloud code(JS SDK), but I just want to see the logic, so please suggest me a query for any SDK as per your convenience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @knshn, that solution makes 2 api requests - one for deleting and one for adding new row. Currently, what Ive done is instead of deleting the rows,  I update the actionType of exisitng row, say "follow" to "unfollow" and I've created 2 additional columns in the table - "latestFollowedDate" & "latestUnfollowedDate", I store the current date in any of these depending on the type of operation. This way I make only 1 api request to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the unfollowing method [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-iOS/Anypic/PAPUtility.m#L269), you can see that it deletes the follow activities. So finding the followers of B is a simple query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[query whereKey:kPAPActivityToUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]]; //Current user is B
[query whereKey:kPAPActivityTypeKey equalTo:kPAPActivityTypeFollow];
```